# How can I access a Vagrant Config object as a string variable in a Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

A Vagrant base box sets `config.ssh.username` to a certain value. I have a `Vagrantfile` where I want to use that value in a string. If I create a string like `"prefix_#{config.ssh.username}_suffix"` the expansion looks like `prefix_\#\<Object:0x000000010127e780\>_suffix`. How can I get the string value that was stored in the `config.ssh` namespace?